# How to show all XML Attribute values thru PHP Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, xml, loops

I am using this code and i am just getting 1 Sports data not all and its just repeating 1 Odds data . Please check

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');

foreach($xml->Game->children() as $a => $b) {
    echo $b['Name'].$b['ID'].'<br>';
    foreach($xml->Game->SportsBook->children() as $c => $d) {
        echo $d['LineType'].$d['LastUpdated'].'<br>';

    }
}
print_r($xml->Game->SportsBook)
?>
```

Comment: Why you are using foreach inside foreach?

Comment: To get SportsBook children values

Comment: but I am not able to see, there is any dependency to use in another foreach, you can do it outside of first foreach

Comment: ok But its just showing 1st Game SportBook values . how it will show all Games data

Comment: can you please `print_r($xml->Game->SportsBook)` and update in question

Comment: Please check now

Comment: It does't seems to be `print_r()` o/p .FYI... you need to place `print_r($xml->Game->SportsBook)` outside foreach

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were having problems understanding the nesting of the data, I think this will give you a better starting point...

```
foreach($xml->Game->SportsBook as $d) {
    echo $d['Name'].' '.$d['ID'].'<br>';
    foreach( $d->Odds as $odds) {
        echo $odds['LineType'].' '.$odds['LastUpdated']."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alot . you are great !